# Polygon triangulation with collinear points?

Tags: node.js, three.js, triangulation

I have a polygon with collinear points. I want to triangulate the polygon while retaining all the collinear points, since I require those vertices on the generated meshes. Currently I tried to use `poly2tri`, but it doesn't support collinear points. Is there a polygon triangulation algorithm which support collinear points?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking for but are you familiar with this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation

Probably not the most effecient way, but you could maybe even use this: https://github.com/ironwallaby/delaunay if you know which points are colinear, (or close) and transform them to a plane.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the points slightly, so they are not colinear. Doing the meshing and then moving the points back.

I tried running the meshing algorithm, then perturbing all the points it missed, then running it again.

It can be quite slow but it does work.

Comment: How can check if these points are collinear?

Answer (score 0):

A simple polygon with collinear vertices presents a serious problem for the "ear splitting" triangulation.  The best example to see this problem - sketch yourself a 5-point star.  Pick any of the points as the convex vertex for a candidate ear.
The diagonal for this ear lies completely within the polygon, and doesn't form "X" intersections with any of the other edges, so by the criteria for a "valid diagonal", it should work.  But, notice that once you slice off the ear, the remaining polygon is no longer a simple polygon - because it contains two vertices where the edges meet at a straight (180 deg.) angle.  That alone disqualifies the new sub-polygon as "simple", and it will crash any attempt to continue triangulation on it using ear-splitting.  I will post a separate question on how best to triangulate these ill-conditioned polys.